# Return values of two column as key-value to lists or dicts in Python-Pandas, SQLAchemy or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have table `code_name` as below(MySQL), from A to W total 23 type and 999 items:

```
id   type       code    name
-----------------------------
1     A          0      Male
2     A          1     Female
3     B          2      Adult
4     B          3      Child
5     C          C4      Aisa
6     C          C5     Europe
7     C          C6     Africa
8     D          D7     Python
9     D          D8      Java
10    D          D9      Golang
11    D          D10     PHP
12    D          D11     Javascript

997   W          886    China
998   W          65    Singapore
999   W          81     Japan
```

My expected output as below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "A": {
            "0": "Male",
            "1": "Female"
        },
        "B": {
            "2": "Adult",
            "3": "Child"
        },
        ..
        ..
        ..
         "W": {
            "886": "China",
            "65": "Singapore",
            "81": "Japan"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to get data as below code(Python, SQL and SQLAlchemy), but the below code is ugly and stupid, is there an easy way to use `pandas` or `numpy` to solve it, anyway, no matter it's a SQL way or a `sqlalchemy` way.

```py
def get_code_name(self):
    query_sql_a = """
        SELECT code,name
        FROM code_name
        WHERE type = "A"
    """
    .....
    .....
    query_sql_w = """
        SELECT code,name
        FROM code_name
        WHERE type = "W"
    """
    result_a = db.session.execute(query_sql_a)
    ...
    ...
    result_b = db.session.execute(query_sql_w)



    # or use below code to get result from A to W total 23 items  
    result_a = db.session.query(
        CodeName.code, CodeName.name
    ).filter(
        CodeName.type ="A"
    ).order_by(
        CodeName.id.asc()
    )

    for d in result_a:
        A = dict(zip(d.keys(), d))
    ...
    ...
    for d in result_w:
        W = dict(zip(d.keys(), d))

    return dict(
        A=A,
        B=B,
        C=C,
        D=D,
        ...
        ...
        W=W
    )
```

Comment: what database flavor are you using

Comment: Hi, I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of grouping in the database and using built-in functions to do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

```
def get_code_name(self):
    query_sql_a = """
        SELECT type, JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                "code", code, "name", name
            )
        )
        FROM code_name
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 1 ASC
    """
    result = db.session.execute(query_sql)
```

This should return you something that looks like the following.

```
[
    ("A", [{"code": 0, "name": "Male"}, {"code": 1, "name": "Female"}]),
    ...
]
```

Then you can just iterate over the results and format it accordingly.

```
output = dict()

for row in result:
    type_, arr = row
    fmtd = {d["code"]: d["name"] for d in json.loads(arr)}
    output[type_] = fmtd
```

The variable `ouput` would then look like the desired output.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your quick reply, I tried your code, and get the error of `ERROR in get_code_name: string indices must be integers`

Comment: it's kind of hard for me to debug without seeing all the code, I gave you the framework for how to structure your code, you can debug these minor errors yourself

Comment: this line need to be changed intto fmtd = {d["code"]: d["name"] for d in json.loads(arr)}

Comment: ahh I thought it would get converted in to it's Python type, I will update the code accordingly